# Excel Online get username and email of person changing a cell value

Tags: excel, office365, power-automate, office-scripts

I have an excel spreadsheet that I upload online (on SharePoint) and share with 100+ users asking for verification of transactions. Users will indicate in column C with either "Valid" or "Not Valid" option from a dropdown list for their respective transaction/invoice charge. I want to be able to record the user's name and email address in columns D and E respectively automatically for auditing purposes. How do I go about doing this? Office Scripts? Excel and PowerAutomate? Please help.

I've tried Excel Online and PowerAutomate but cannot get it to work. I'm struggling with either the connector between the two. Nor can i get it to work to trigger upon cell change and grab the user name and email address. Nor do I know how to then write back the user name and email address back onto the excel file.
I've tried office scripts but I used a code i found online and it doesnt seem to work. I keep getting a bunch of errors. I have no coding experience whatsoever.

Comment: Office Scripts lacks support for worksheet change events as is available in VBA.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible solution/workflow -

- Imagine you have a table like this in your workbook:
  [image: A sample table in Excel]
- Build a form on https://forms.microsoft.com/ to ask the user select `Valid` or `Not Valid` to verify the transaction:
  [image: A sample form to collect verifications]
- Create a manual triggered flow. This flow will go through each row in the table that hasn't been verified and send an email to `Recipient` to ask them to verify the transaction details by clicking a link pointing to the above form. You can probably include the transaction in the email so they can directly read it there. You can run this flow periodically to send reminders to whomever hasn't submitted their verification response yet. You can even convert this flow into a time-based recurring trigger that will automatically run based on a schedule.
  [image: A sample Power Automate flow]
- Create another flow triggered by the form submission. This flow will read the form submission and update the transaction workbook based on the response each user has chosen in the form. It will also automatically log the recipient email and submission time.
  [image: Another sample Power Automate flow]

Now, when you are ready to collect the verifications, you can just run the first flow to send out emails to everyone.

The recipient will get an email like this:
[image: A sample email]

If they click on the "Verify" link, they will be directed to the above form to verify the transaction.

Once they have submitted the form, your transaction table will become this (you can see Alan has just submitted his response):
[image: Sample table after a submission]

You don't necessarily have to share that transaction workbook to everyone since they can just read the email to learn about the transaction details. This can also prevent them from accidentally messing up with your workbook, etc.

This might not exactly be what you originally wanted but hopefully it could be useful for some similar scenarios.

Please note both the **List rows present in a table** and the **Update a row** actions in the two flows can be replaced by **Run script** actions if you need more complex scenarios - for example, you want to extract some data or chart from the workbook as a snapshot included in the email, or you have some complex logic when updating the tracking table, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. This is great. But question - how do you accomodate 5 or 6 or more items that a person is responsible for being it in the email or in the form? Would your set up mean each person will receive 5-6 emails for each item?

Comment: In this case, I was wondering if **Office Scripts** (vs. the **List rows** action) suits better here, where we can write some script to filter and extract each user's transactions list and generate a summarized HTML table that can be passed to the **Send email** action. I'll see if I can find some time to write up an updated solution. Feel free to tinker around on your side as well!